# Can't start mysql (Homebrew Mac M1)

Tags: mysql, macos, homebrew, macos-monterey

I have a error when i try to run the MYSQL server

When i try to run with brew services start mysql, return me this error

```html
brew services start mysgl
Bootstrao failed: 5: Inout/outout error
Try re-running the command as root for richer errors
Error: Failure while executina;
`/bin/launchetl bootstrap qui/501 /Users/<user>
/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist`exited with 5
```

If i ran this with sudo don't work

```html
%
sudo brew services start mysgl
Warning: Taking root:admin ownership of some mysql paths:
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql/8.0.30_1/bin
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysq1/8.0.30_1/bin/mysqld_safe
/opt/homebrew/opt/mysql
/opt/homebrew/opt/mysql/bin
/opt/homebrew/var/homebrew/linked/mvsal
This will require manual removal of these paths using
sudo rm' on
brew upgrade/reinstall/uninstall.
Warning: mysql must be run as non-root to start at user login!
/Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist:servic ealready bootstrapped
Bootstrap failed: 37: Operation already in progress
Error: Failure while executing: `/bin/launchctl bootstrap system /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist`exited with 37
<user>~ % brew services list
Name status User File
mysql stopped root ~/Librarv/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mvsal.olist
```

I was try to unistall and install the HomeBrew and the MYSQL again but always had the same ¡s errors.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: [**Please Never** post images of or off site links to code, data or error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2310830). Please edit your question and include copy/paste the text into the question, formatted. 
This is so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: Did you have a look at the MySQL error log

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not a real answer:

If it is not absolutely required for you to run it as a native process, run it in docker.

Besides that: mysql wants to run as root, as the error message says. Maybe you need to correct the mode bits. Inspect the brew post installation steps carefully, usually there is a hing or command to execute.